# Allowing fixed-length of video recording in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-capture

I want to allow user to record a fixed-length video in Windows Phone 7.

for example while user capturing a video if recording time passes more than 3 minutes. It should popup a message and stop the recording.

So my problem is how to check the video length(time).

I am thinking i would create a timer to calculate/check the elapsed time when user starts a video. if elapsed time goes beyond the recording limit, programatically stop the recording.

Please suggest me if anyone have better thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your own timer that will keep track of the recorded time is the **optimal** solution here, since you don't want to constantly read the file length and perform media structure manipulations to determine the length.